# How to install one certificate automated into Firefox store?

Tags: firefox, certificate

I have a app (.NET) that automatically adds a certificate to the Windows root store via:

```
X509Store rootStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
rootStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
rootStore.Add(certificate);
rootStore.Close();
```

Internet Explorer then knows this certificate. But Firefox don't as it has its own certificate store.

Is there any way to accomplish this without overriding current Firefox certificates (read somewhere to copy cert8.db but thats not possible due to multiple customers)?

I simply want to automatically "add" one certificate to the Firefox store.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try which already works nearly as I want:

The documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil

I downloaded the binaries from:
https://www.felixrr.pro/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/nss-3.13.5-nspr-4.9.1-compiled-x86.zip

Then run the following commands from within the extracted zip-directory (otherwise CMD would use certutil of Windows) which worked:

```
// Add certificate to cert8.db (Db will be reloaded on next FF start)
certutil.exe -A -n "SomeName" -t "Cu,p,p" -i "C:\Test\cert.pem" -d "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5drs48sb.default"

// Show all certificates in cert8.db
certutil.exe -L -d "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5drs48sb.default"
```

After restarting FF I could successfully navigate to my SSL page without certificate error.

The only command that didnt work yet is the delete command which returns the error 'certutil.exe: could not find certificate named "SomeName": security library: bad database.':

```
certutil.exe -D -n "SomeName" -d "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5drs48sb.default"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS) to manage certificates on the local install. Not sure how well it plays with .NET (if at all) but if the environment is predictable you could probably resort to running an executable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can call some *.exe within my .NET code so its probably okay. Few questions: a) Does it install the cert for all profiles? b) Has the Firefox to be closed when installing?

Comment: Don't know, never used it myself. Profiles all have their own cert database so I imagine you'd need to do each one separately.